# How to make selected h:selectOneRadio of h:dataTable remain selected on postback?

Tags: jsf, datatable, jsf-2.2, selectoneradio

In normal circumstances like this:

```
  <h:form>           
    <h:selectOneRadio value="#{bean.gender}">
        <f:selectItem itemValue="Male" itemLabel="Male" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="Female" itemLabel="Female" />
        <f:selectItem itemValue="Other" itemLabel="Other" />
    </h:selectOneRadio>
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{bean.action}" />
  </h:form>
```

Selecting one radio button disselects the other & the radio button will be remain selected on the postback. (when the same view is rendered)

However, when we're dealing with an iterating component like `<h:dataTable>`, the selection is lost.

Consider the snippet:

```
        <h:form id="hashMapFormId">           
            <b>HASH MAP:</b>
            <h:dataTable value="#{playersBean.dataHashMap.entrySet()}" var="t" border="1">
                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">Select</f:facet>
                    <h:selectOneRadio id="radiosId" onclick="deselectRadios(this.id);" 
                                        value="#{playersBean.select}">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="null"/>
                    </h:selectOneRadio>
                </h:column> 
            </h:dataTable>
            <h:commandButton value="Show Hash Map Selection" 
                             action="#{playersBean.showSelectedPlayer()}" />
        </h:form>
```

With disselecting the other radio buttons when one radio button is selected being implemented by simple JavaScript-

```
            function deselectRadios(id) {

                var f = document.getElementById("hashMapFormId");
                for (var i = 0; i < f.length; i++)
                {
                    var e = f.elements[i];
                    var eid = e.id;
                    if (eid.indexOf("radiosId") !== -1) {
                        if (eid.indexOf(id) === -1) {
                            e.checked = false;
                        } else {
                            e.checked = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Fire the GET request:
[image]

Select a radio button:
[image]

Now press the submit button, response:
[image]

You see that the radio button gets dis selected on postback. How to solve this shortcoming?

I know it very well that this is due to this component attribute `itemValue` being `null`:

```
<f:selectItem itemValue="null"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This trick is a leftover from JSF 1.x / 2.0/2.1 when it wasn't possible to use a `<h:selectOneRadio>` for single row selection in a `<h:dataTable>`. This trick originated in my 10 year old blog article [Using Datatables - Select row by radio button](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2006/06/using-datatables.html#SelectRowByRadioButton).

The root problem is, HTML radio buttons are grouped based on their `name` attribute, so the webbrowser knows which others to unselect when one is selected. But JSF generates by design a different one for each `<h:dataTable>` item, with the row index inlined and therefore they can't be grouped and hence the JavaScript based workaround.

Since JSF 2.2, with the new [passthrough elements and attributes](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets009.htm) feature, it's however possible to force the `name` attribute to the value of your choice and capture the selected item via a helper `<h:inputHidden>`. This is fleshed out in another blog article of me, from previous year: [Custom layout with h:selectOneRadio in JSF 2.2](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2015/10/custom-layout-with-hselectoneradio-in.html). The article uses `<ui:repeat>` as an example, this can be rewritten to `<h:dataTable>` as below.

```
<h:form>
    <h:dataTable value="#{bean.items}" var="item">
        <h:column>
            <input type="radio" jsf:id="item" a:name="#{hiddenItem.clientId}"
                value="#{item.id}" a:checked="#{item.id eq bean.selectedItemId ? 'checked' : null}" />
        </h:column>
        <h:column>#{item.id}</h:column>
        <h:column>#{item.name}</h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
    <h:inputHidden id="selectedItem" binding="#{hiddenItem}" value="#{bean.selectedItemId}"
        rendered="#{facesContext.currentPhaseId.ordinal ne 6}" />
    <h:commandButton id="submit" value="Submit" action="#{bean.submit}" />
</h:form>
```

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    private List<Item> items;
    private Long selectedItemId;

    // ...

    public void submit() {
        System.out.println("Selected item ID: " + selectedItemId);
    }

    // ...
}
```

And yes, the selected radio button remains selected on postback this way. You can also pass whole entities, this only requires a converter on the `<h:inputHidden>`.