# How can I write xhtml code with if of a JSF variable?

Tags: html, forms, jsf, jsf-2, radio-button

I would like add `checked` in a `input type = "radio"` if a variable is `true`. This is my simple code:

```
<input type="radio" <!-- here I need a checked: #{(myBean.variable == true) print(checked)}--> />
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does the concrete problem you're actually trying to solve boil down to this http://stackoverflow.com/q/7435039? Or perhaps this http://stackoverflow.com/q/38038557?

Comment: Why aren't you using `h:selectOneRadio`?